# How do I check the performance of my apk?

Tags: unity, performance

I have developed an app with Unity 5.2 for the Android platform. The app is running perfectly, but it's loading time is about 7 to 10 seconds, at least, on my Samsung S5.

The first scene that takes time to load contains 6 canvases for different UI purposes. It is mandatory for me to retain these 6 canvases, as my code relies on them. I can't go back from here.

How do I check the performance of my apk, and find the source of my problem?

Comment: So, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: do canvas effect performance ?

Comment: They do. But to check if it is really affecting your game's performance, try running the game with profiler.

Comment: apk with profiler?

Comment: No. Run you game on your the device with **Development Build** and **Autoconnect Profiler** options checked in the build settings. @Spectre has given a more detailed and step by step answer.

Comment: deployment is still in progress from last 10 minutes is this normal? i used build and run

Comment: for checking performance, you could also limit unity to one core and look at the profiler that way, but you should really edit your question and actually ask something.

Comment: i edit it sir please check it. and also comments

Comment: Given your previous comments, I accept that this question is still unclear as to what your actually trying to ask. For example, I fail to see how you could be asking "what does this information mean" if you initially had to ask "how do I check the information".

Comment: By the way, more canvasses = better anyway. Due to the way Unity handles the drawing of canvasses, you will want to separate out elements of your UI anyway, so that areas that never change (or change rarely) are isolated from areas that do change every frame. Check out [this talk](https://youtu.be/n-oZa4Fb12U). However, the number of canvasses probably is not affecting *load* time.

Comment: @Draco18s you are right, the number of canvasses is not affecting load time. I checked that i have multiple cameras that affecting performance

Comment: Oh yeah *THAT'D* do it. Every camera has to render the scene. It's like trying to get three, four, six times the frame rate.

Answer (score 4):

`Canvas` affects performance, but not as much as particles, wrong shaders and too many graphics. If the loading time is >7 - profiler is the best option, because you probably have some RAM/draw problems.

From [Unity Forums](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/32368/how-do-i-profile-on-an-android-device.html):

- Make sure to disable Mobile Data on your Android device.
- Connect your Android device to your WiFi network.
- Check the "Autoconnect Profiler" checkbox in Unity's build settings dialog.
- Attach your device to your Mac/PC via cable and hit "Build & Run" in Unity Editor.
- When the app launches on the device, open the profiler window in Unity Editor (Window->Profiler)
- If the Unity Editor fails to autoconnect to the device, select the appropriate device from the Profiler Window Active Profiler drop down menu.

Comment: i am trying your answer and during build it is pushing new content to device xyz. from last 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way to go about testing performance of your game but you usually want to use the [Unity's built-in profiler](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/temas/performance-optimization/profiler-window), which has a manual [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerWindow.html).

This allows you to see how much of each resources your game is using. You need to dive into the details below and see what's using what, and then optimize by working around the problems or optimizing your code if necessary.

Now, the first way to use the profiler is to just run the game on your computer and look at the results there. This will probably not be very useful by itself since your CPU is probably (and hopefully) much more powerful than your phone's or tablet's. So, you need to [limit the CPUs that Unity uses](https://superuser.com/questions/309617/how-to-limit-a-process-to-a-single-cpu-core) while testing (don't forget to let Unity use all of them when you're done testing). This method is usually much faster than the second one.

The second method would be to use your phone. Either connect your phone to your computer and just use the [build and run option](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/mobile-touch/building-your-unity-game-android-device-testing) Unity provides or send the APK to your phone, install the game and then connect your phone to your computer, then use the profiler to connect to your device. Both will let you test the performance of your game but both are slower to test the performance (in terms of the time it takes from "ready to test the game" to "actually testing the game") than the first method, which allows you to stop the program and then start it again without waiting for a build and an APK installation.

Comment: Have you actually checked out the first two links that I provided? Unity does a pretty good job of explaining what does what in their own profiler. @Gnemlock

Comment: I have, but I do not judge answers based off links. They are *helpful*, but not in regards to the static value of an answer.